# Does the Archivist actually delete my file if its card dies?

Tags: inscryption

During my fight with the The Archivist, they asked me to to select the oldest file saved on my computer. The Archivist turned my file into a card and said it would be deleted if the card died. I won the fight without my card dying, so I never found out:

Would The Archivist have actually deleted my file if the card was destroyed?

[image: "For, if this card dies, I will delete the file from your disk."]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it will not actually delete your files. As you can see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/inscryption/comments/qcxsa7/spoilers_does_the_archivist_really_erase_files/), it's a joke.

Comment: I think there is an achievement if you do that for him.